# When is Deep Fritz 15 release date?

Tags: engines, fritz

I try searching the release date, but I couldn't find it. How much later do the deep version of a chess software come out?

Answer (score 1):

According to the website for This Week In Chess, the release date for Fritz 15 is November 27, 2015. Also note that now they only sell one version of the product. There no longer is a separate Deep version.